# OData Hangs Forever in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, odata, xamarin.forms

I am trying to fetch data from the Nortwind URL with using Simple.OData.Client in Xamarin form. Application hangs forever. The simple project source code is in the following link: [Download](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2Yf2EqUAx61bDhLVFhKNUFQbEU/edit)

```cs
using Simple.OData.Client;

public async void InitializeDataService(){

    try {
        mODataClient = new ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");
    }

    catch {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection Error", "OK", "Cancel");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR!");
    }
}

public async void GetDataFromOdataService (string myDataClicked){

    try {
        myCustomers= mODataClient.For(myDataClicked).Top(10).FindEntriesAsync().Result;
    }

    catch {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection Error", "OK", "Cancel");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR!");
    }
}
```

**Update:1** I have updated my code based on Pete suggestion. Still hangs forever.

```cs
private ODataClient mODataClient;
private IEnumerable <IDictionary<string,object>> myCustomers;
public ObservableCollection <Customer>Customers { get; set;}
public string myDataString;

public MyDataServices (string myDataClicked)
{
    Title="Customers";
    myDataString = myDataClicked;
    callServices();
}

public async Task callServices()
{
    await InitializeDataService ();
    await GetDataFromOdataService (myDataString);   
}

public async Task InitializeDataService(){

    try {
        mODataClient = 
            new ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");
    }
    catch {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection Error", "OK", "Cancel");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR!");
    }
}

public async Task GetDataFromOdataService (string myDataClicked){

    try {
        myCustomers= mODataClient.For(myDataClicked).Top(10).FindEntriesAsync().Result;
    }
    catch {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Connection Error", "OK", "Cancel");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is hanging due how your trying to call **async** and making it synchronous.

Where you are doing this, I take you are just doing this as a test at present, and that later on you will expand upon as at present your variable is only local to that function.

So try doing `public static async Page GetMainPage()`, and changing to:-

```
var customers= await mODataClient.For("Customers").Top(10).FindEntriesAsync();
```

as it is most likely hanging on your previous implementation.

Note you will most likely have to do **async** declaration and put in an **await** to the page that calls the **GetMainPage()** function also to get all this working.

Really - though - I would take this as a Task<> function and await it from within the Page that you are displaying.

**Update 1:-**

Issue was related to **async** / **await** issues.

Data task was separated out into a separate function returning a **Task<>**, subsequently updating the **ListView.ItemsSource** control when the data is retrieved.

Comment: Hello Pete. It seems I am missing some minor things that does not allow my app to run.I have sent you my source code via email.

Comment: Hello Pete, I have updated my code based on your suggestion, it still hangs forever.

Comment: I just sent you an email with the fix.  It works for me.  Try and let me know?

Answer (score 1):

As Pete suspected, the application hangs most likely due to your attempt to run it synchronously. Inspect the source code and revise all places where you call .Result or .Wait(). Then it should work. I know such refactoring may require substantial code rewrite, but that's the way to go.